# Send E-mail if date has passed using php

Tags: php, sql, email

I'm trying to make an online sign up sheet system. I was just wondering if when the date of the event had passed would I be able to send a list of all the people who have signed up to the event (from the MySQL database)to an e-mail, but only do this once? I would imagine you have to compare the date now to the start date, but how do I stop it re-sending more than once?

I'm not asking for a fully written script just an idea of how to go about it.

Many thanks

Comment: use a cronjob, you will need to keep a record of who has had a message sent too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot do that out-of-the-box, because you cannot start a periodic task to be executed every so often (or on a specific point in time).

Thus, you have two options:

- Start the sending using an external mechanism, such as `CRON` on Linux. There is functionality like this on every platform. This basically means that you instruct some program or OS component to visit a particular page every, say, 5 minutes to check if there is new mail to send. Google for **php cron** for an example. Google for **php cron windows** for hints on how to do that on Windows.
- You just check if there is new mail to send whenever somebody visits the page for any reason. This has obvious disadvantages, but doesn't require you to set up a new system.

Comment: if each event was only to be sent once and to the same single e-mail address could you use php, or should I look deeper into cronjobs?

Comment: @ByronFitzgerald I'd go for cronjobs (or the equivalent on a non-UNIX platform). This is actually easy, you just need to set it up to run every X minutes. Everything else you do in PHP: Check if the last task has already finished, then check if there's new mail to send, send it, and mark the e-mails as sent.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer has been helpful, you should mark it as _accepted_. That will help others spot questions faster that are unanswered yet.